# How to enable multiple users Windows 10 through RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I am looking for a trick that can allow me to access to a Windows 10 workstation using RDP with two different users.
anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Only Windows 10 Enterprise (and Server) supports allowing multiple users to log into it simultaneously.

Comment: What about Windows 10 Professional ??

Comment: reefer back to my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

@Ramhound is correct, Microsoft did this by design. You could use VNC, but you'd be sharing the same mouse-cursor/screen. If you're looking for a multiseat setup than you either have to get another version of windows or better a dedicated solution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration

Comment: So I need to install the Windows 10 Enterprise version to apply this feature, right?

Comment: @mohamedEl-ghorfi - If you want to be legal, that is indeed, the case.

Comment: @Ramhound- I have a reason to apply this, I have a Shared Machine that runs Windows 0 pro, and there are 3 persons needs to login simultaneous.

Comment: We are not questioning the motives, we are just saying that the EULA and this software restriction go hand in hand and you are therefore probably breaking the terms of the EULA.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is actually built into all Windows versions since Vista, but not enabled unless you've paid for the enterprisey enough version. There's a project called [RDP Wrapper](https://github.com/sebaxakerhtc/rdpwrap/releases) that enables it.

It does work. However it's **detected as malware by multiple antivirus products** and may not be as stable as Microsoft's original RDP setup. Use it at your own risk.

**Do not disable your antivirus** to get it to work. Add it to ignored files instead. If you don't know how to do that and can't find it on the Internet on your own, you probably shouldn't be taking this risk.